# Install graphics card hardware drivers via remote desktop in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, drivers, graphics-card

I come across the same problem over and over. I working on computer that is remote and it is missing graphics card drivers. Just has some default drivers that have limited resolution.

I would like to install program that will read the chipset on graphics card and tell me the values so I can go on manufacturer website and download the appropriate drivers.

Windows 7 or Windows XP application would do, if you know about any.

This is what GPUZ is giving me (the rest of the tabs are pretty much empty): 
[image]

---

And CPUZ is giving this:
[image]

---

And Belarc Advisor is no better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) instead, or [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html)

[image: GPU-Z]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CPUZ](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to tell what graphics card/chipset is installed. Although I'm not sure if it uses the driver to do this, however it's such a small program that it's at least worth trying.

[image]

Comment: That was first thing I tried. It did work just showed me Standard VGA Adapter.

Comment: Sorry @Mat Banik that was my best guess... You should probably include what you have tried in the question so you don't get more answers like this.